# Windows Task Scheduler run task when Taskbar is available

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

I am trying to create a scheduled event that will fire when a user logs on. The window application (written in .NET/C#) is starting minimized with an icon in the Traybar. I now encountered an issue when Windows is asking for activation, the application starts prematurely. This also breaks the application's possibility to be placed in the Traybar after the activation window closes. My application minimizes in the direction of the Windows-Button but will be shown as a minimized window with Titlebar.

[image: Window minimized]

I placed the application in the Task Scheduler during an installation process because it requires elevated rights to run. How can I create a reliable Trigger in the Task Scheduler to start the application when the desktop is loaded?

Comment: I don't understand. Is your application only supposed to run on a non-activated version of Windows? If not then surely you can expect the user to have an activated version?

Comment: I am using one of the [VMs Microsoft provides](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) with different Browser version. There I've noticed that the Task Scheduler doesn't do this what I would expect. I want to run a task once the Taskbar is loaded - not before. Yes, 99% of the time Windows should be activated, but this is a corner case I would also like to cover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger this batch script at startup. It waits for explorer.exe to start (which the taskbar is implemented into) ***then*** starts the app:

```
:waitingfortaskbar 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>nul | find /I /N "explorer.exe">nul
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto startapp
goto waitingfortaskbar
:startapp
REM ping localhost -n 1 -w 10> nul
start DriverLetter:\...MyProgramLocation...\MyProgram.exe -myArguments
exit
```

If you want to, delay the task, just remove `REM` and replace `10` milliseconds with however milliseconds you want; You may have to do so if the taskbar isn't setup instantly after explorer.exe like it should. Then replace the `start` line with the actual file location and it's arguments (if any).

The program will show command prompt until explorer.exe starts; If you want to make it invisible just comment me. I have two options in mind.

Comment: I was worried that I needed a workaround since what I am trying to achieve is not directly supported by Task Scheduler. Thanks for the bat script - my knowledge is very limited, but I will give this a try and come back to you! Big Thanks for now!

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add another possibility that works based on the solution from El8tedN8te; however, it is vb script:

```
Function ProcessRunning(process)

    SET objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    SET colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select Name from Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '" & process & "%'")

    IF colProcessList.count>0 THEN
        ProcessRunning = 1
    ELSE
        ProcessRunning = 0
    END IF 

    SET objWMIService = Nothing
    SET colProcessList = Nothing

End Function

' Check if the task is already running
taskRunning = ProcessRunning("{taskFilename}")
IF taskRunning THEN
  WScript.Quit 0
END IF

' Check if required task is already running
requiredTaskRunning = ProcessRunning("explorer.exe")
DO WHILE requiredTaskRunning = 0
    WScript.Sleep 5000
    requiredTaskRunning = ProcessRunning("explorer.exe")
LOOP

DIM oShell
SET oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run """{taskDirectory}{taskFilename}"" {taskArguments}", 1
SET oShell = Nothing
```

The vbs script engine does not show any window while its running. Therefore, I do not have to worry about hiding the bat/cmd window.
The text {between} the curly parentheses is replaced by my application at runtime and then saved as a .vbs file. Then, a Task is scheduled to run the vbs with elevated rights.

This is probably not the most secure way of doing it, but this did the trick for me. Comments are still welcome.

Comment: Nice! Your answer is much better than mine. Except could you edit it so that you explicitly reference that explorer.exe is what you are testing? Just for other viewers of course.

Comment: I updated! Thanks again, you've put me in the right direction.